# how to read a txt and delimit it by pipes

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a txt file with the following form:

```
1 | Argentina |Y|POSTAL_C |CAPITAL|STATES
```

I would like to convert each of these positions separated by the "|", be it a position within an example array like this:

```
0 |   1       |2|3        |4      |5
1 | Argentina |Y|POSTAL_C |CAPITAL|STATES
```

and work them inside an array

```
My code

public void ReadFile2() throws IOException {
    String referencePath = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\PRUEBA.txt";
    BufferedReader br;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(referencePath));

    String lines = br.readLine();
            lines.split("\n", 6);

    this.logger.info("Starting...");

    while (lines != null) {
        if (!lines.isEmpty() && lines.length() >7) {
            String[] values = lines.split("|");

            System.out.println(values[0]); ----> should return 1
        }
      lines = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();


}
```

grateful for your comments

Comment: `split()` invoked on a String returns an array of Strings. When you do `lines.split("\r", 6);` and don't assign it to anything, that call to split does nothing because the value it returns is lost. Your while loop will most likely be endless because lines still holds the result of `br.readLine()` and thus will never be null. I have no idea why you check if the lenght of your string is greater than 7. If the file has multiple lines, the loop should encompass the reading of the line, or you will only read one line.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate first through the line break, "\ n", and then through the pipe separation, in order to access the object, do you have any ideas how to resolve what you start in your comment? @JustAnotherDeveloper

Comment: a call to `split("|");` on the String that holds the value of the line you read would give you what you want.

Comment: .split("|") dont work men xd 
I already tried that @JustAnotherDeveloper

Comment: Check the edit I made to my previous comment. It works if you split by "\\|"

Comment: BufferedReader#readline() doesn't return the line delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Because String you pass to `split` method should be a regex you need to use `lines.split("\\|")`.

In regex pipe sign have special meaning (it works like OR operator) so you need to escape it by backslash. In java string literal backslash have special meaning because it's escape following character so you that's way two backslashes here. Result String is in fact just `\|`.

Try this:

```
String test = "1 | Argentina |Y|POSTAL_C |CAPITAL|STATES";
String[] values = test.split("\\|");
for (String value : values) {
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

This returns output:

```
1
Argentina
Y
POSTAL_C
CAPITAL
STATES
```

Probably you would like also to `.trim()` particular values to remove unnecessary white spaces.